# UK tv episode about a boy with mental powers

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw this on UK tv sometime between 1964 and 1972.
Maybe an episode of "Out of the unknown" or a similar series. I saw it in B&W

There was a teenage schoolboy who wore glasses and looked a nerd type. At weekends he did like a hypnosis show in shabby little nightclubs.
(I think he was accompanied by an older female, possibly his agent or big sister)

The act was getting semi drunk people to squawk like chickens or dance like Elvis etc and usually raised a few laughs.

One night he came up against Mr belligerent drunk who was not impressed, I think he shouted or pushed at the female and he was suddenly vocally dominated by the schoolboy with the power.

I think (but I'm not sure) that the drunk either cuts himself with a broken bottle or burns himself with a lighter while the crowd roars in dismay - there is a man in  the shadows watching all this.

The man questions people after the boy has left and gets his name and location, the man reveals he's a British secret operative tasked with tracking down what he calls mutants. He then gets to the youths residence and gets chatting with him to find if he has any siblings, suddenly he whips out a hypodermic needle to inject the boy, but he spotted reflection in the window and says "stop' and the man freezes.

There was a short discussion to learn why he was under attack, then he orders the agent to inject himself in the neck vein, he's pleading "No, please, not this stuff, please not this" the needle plunges and he falls dead.

It ends with the boy and the older female heading out of town but he knows now that there's nowhere safe to go, he's on a death list

Comment: Possibly the original version of The Tomorrow People? That had kids with powers including telepathy but I don't know if hypnosis was involved.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Unlikely to be The Tomorrow People as the description sounds far too violent for kids' TV.

Comment: "the drunk either cuts himself with a broken bottle or burns himself with a lighter while the crowd roars in dismay" — in dismay? Yet just 2–3 short decades later, _Jackass_ is a smash hit.

Comment: Soz
Not the tomorrow people, maybe a few years older than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Series - *Journey To The Unknown*,
Episode - *Stranger In The Family*
Jan 16th 1969

You've got some of the details wrong, but there's enough matches to be sure it's the right story. Maybe you are conflating two different stories, but this is one of them

Full episode on Youtube.

Man hunting for 'mutants' [at this point](https://youtu.be/4VqhhYGMhpM?t=2033).

Dealing with angry spectator [at this point](https://youtu.be/4VqhhYGMhpM?t=2238).

Comment: Awesome, cheers